# java.lang.VerifyError when trying to mock javax.sql.DataSource class

Tags: java, junit, mockito

Here is the block of code that is causing the error:

```
    javax.sql.DataSource dataSourceMock = mock(javax.sql.DataSource.class);
    when(dataSourceMock.getConnection()).thenReturn(mock(Connection.class));

    dummyProcCall = Mockito.spy(new AbstractProcCall(dataSourceMock) {
        @Override
        protected String getProcName() {
            return "Dummy Procedure";
        }
    });
```

Stacktrace is:

```
    java.lang.VerifyError: (class: $javax/sql/DataSource$$EnhancerByMockitoWithCGLIB$$7d15913f, method: getConnection signature: ()Ljava/sql/Connection;) Inconsistent stack height 0 != 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedSerializationConstructorAccessor3.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.objenesis.instantiator.sun.SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.newInstance(SunReflectionFactoryInstantiator.java:45)
    at org.objenesis.ObjenesisBase.newInstance(ObjenesisBase.java:73)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.createProxy(ClassImposterizer.java:142)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:61)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.jmock.ClassImposterizer.imposterise(ClassImposterizer.java:52)
    at org.mockito.internal.creation.CglibMockMaker.createMock(CglibMockMaker.java:24)
    at org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.createMock(MockUtil.java:32)
    at org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:59)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1258)
    at org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1135)      
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.mockito.internal.runners.JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.run(JUnit45AndHigherRunnerImpl.java:37)
    at org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner.run(MockitoJUnitRunner.java:62)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.execute(JUnit4Provider.java:252)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.executeTestSet(JUnit4Provider.java:141)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider.invoke(JUnit4Provider.java:112)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethodWithArray(ReflectionUtils.java:189)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory$ProviderProxy.invoke(ProviderFactory.java:165)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ProviderFactory.invokeProvider(ProviderFactory.java:85)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:75)
```

Steps I have taken to isolate the issue:

1. Try different JDK versions (JDK 1.7, 1.8)
2. Restart the machine and remove global JAVA_HOME
3. Try running the unit test without the IDE

Comment: Can you post what you have in your classpath?

Comment: My classpath is "-classpath "C:\apache-maven-3.3.9\boot\plexus-classworlds-2.5.2.jar;C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1\lib\idea_rt.jar"

Comment: That is the classpath of your IDE. You should have JUnit, Mokito, etc. on the CP of your app. There is some version conflict between the different libraries you are using.